Is there another representation for the summation: $\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{a_j}{(c+a_j)(c+a_j+1)} $, how to reformulate that to keep $c$ out of the sum
Is there a closed form (without summation) for the summation or at least can I reformulate that so I keep $c$ out of the summation, for example, $c \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(a_n,b_n)$.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n}{(c+b_n)(c+b_n+1)}
$$
where $a_{j},b_{j},c>0$. I have seen some examples in the book of series and integrals:
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac1{[p + (k - 1)q](p + k q)} = \frac n{p(p + n q)} \\
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac1{[p + (k - 1)q](p + k q)[p + (k + 1)q]} = \frac{n(2p + n q + q)}{2p(p + q)(p + n q)[p + (n + 1)q]}.
\end{gather*}
I faced this summation while solving an equation, the final equation was:
$$
\frac{-1}{c^2}+
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n}{(c+b_n)(c+b_n+1)}=0.
$$
I was thinking if I could take $c$ out of the summation in any way, so to solve the equation for $c$.

What exactly do you mean by a "closed-form" ? This sum is finite.

Sorry, I mean without the summation, another representation. I will add a clarification in the mean post. Thank you.

without knowledge of $a_n$ and $b_n$ there is no way to rewrite this sum.

Given that you have $2N+1$ variables, I'm not sure what you're expecting here. Also, please note that you can embed images rather than linking. Finally, your title does not match your question.

Thanks @DaveBenson for the note, I tried to add a picture but it gets converted to a link. Please see my question edited, so you have an idea of what I am expecting. Thank you for any insight for this problem.

@PietroMajer, can you have a look on my question edited? Thank you.

So the real question is solving the equation for $c$?

@DaveBenson, re, new users without an association bonus cannot include images. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83099. (But of course the image could have been transcribed, which I have done.)

If the actual question was about solving the equation, it would be better to address it directly in the  post. A closed form for the sum  may not be relevant to study the equation. You may want to edit accordingly.  In the meanwhile I  wrote some answer/remark  on the equation.

A few words on existence and approximation. Write your equation as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{c^2a_n}{(c+b_n)(c+b_n+1)}=1.$$
There is a nice partial fractions decomposition,
$$\frac{c^2 }{(c+b )(c+b +1)}=1+\frac{b^2}{c+b}-\frac{(b+1)^2}{c+b+1},$$
which is increasing for positive $c$, as one can check from the derivative. Therefore, every term of the LHS of the above equation is continuous and strictly increasing wrto $c$, with values at $0$ and limit at $+\infty$ $0$, resp. $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$.
We conclude that there exists exactly one positive solution $c_*>0$ provided  $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n>1,$ and no solutions if $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\le 1.$
Assuming $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n>1,$ you may approximate  the solution by monotone iteration. Write e.g. the equation as $f(c)=c$ with
$$f(c):= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{c^{\mathbf 3} a_n}{(c+b_n)(c+b_n+1)}, $$
then since by the above observations $f$ is strictly increasing and $f(c)<c$ iff $c<c_*$, you get a monotone sequence  $c_{k+1}:=f(c_k)$ converging to $c_*$ (increasing or decreasing, provided that $c_0<c_*$ or $c_0>c_*$)
